# Webpages apache timeout SSL

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, timeout

We have around 40+ webs in our aws instance managed by an apache server, we recently made changes to all the virtual hosts and now the webs are timing out I think because of the the ssl handshake.

I've tried debugging with

`$ openssl s_client -connect example.es:443 -prexit`

and it does not respond properly.

We have a bunch of virtual hosts configurations that look like the following:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.example.es

        DocumentRoot /var/www/example/public

        <Directory "/var/www/example/public">
            AllowOverride all
        </Directory>

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options +FollowSymlinks
            RewriteEngine On
        </IfModule>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.es/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.es/privkey.pem
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule mod_ssl.c>
```

and a bunch https to http redirections like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias www.test.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/test/public
    <Directory "/var/www/test/public">
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName test.com 
    ServerAlias www.test.com
    Redirect permanent / http://test.com/   
</VirtualHost>
```

any tips on what could be causing this or how to debug better? one of the domains that are not working properly is: www.smiletrip.es

Comment: what do you see in logs?

Comment: With `openssl s_client` always add `-servername` otherwise you are not doing SNI and you will have problems connecting to some servers.

Comment: The TLS handshake seems long indeed. Problems with your random source? Also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47446837/tls-handshake-timeout-when-load-testing-using-gatling